# Best way for store a web application settings and options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, settings

i'm working on a ASP.Net MVC 5 web application which it's a blog and has a administrator area. The admin area has some functionality something like which user can comment on the post and etc... but maybe admin changes his mind and he wants to just allow registered users comment. I mean the options be dynamic.

The question is where to store data of these kind of options are the best place?

I'm avoiding from create a table for these data because of frequent queries!

The second idea i have is using database and cache together but i'm looking for the best way to implement that...

Is there a better idea?

Comment: IMHO, you're not really talking about (global) application _settings_ - rather, more along the lines of "business rules" - e.g. "roles", "authorization" - and you _will_ have to check one way or the other for each user/request to a resource.

Comment: No, i mean some global settings just like wordpress that already performed @EdSF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in the database. That part is easy. If you're concerned about querying the database too much, then cache the results of your query for some time period. At its most simplest, that would look something like:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

var key = "MyAwesomeSettings";
var settings = cache.Get(key);
if (settings == null)
{
    settings = // query settings;
    cache.Add(key, settings, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));
}
```

However, one key issue with `MemoryCache` is that it's process-bound. If you're using web workers, you're going to have a unique cache per worker, as each worker is a separate process. You can use a NoSQL solution like Redis, though, to create a distributed cache that can be shared between workers and is more resilient to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Use database tables to store the data, if the amount is not too big, when user logs in, retrieve the data once and store it in user session object for quick access.

Answer (score 1):

I do this same thing in a web application I maintain.  Unless you have a whole lot (like thousands or millions) of different settings or an extremely slow database, saving the settings in the database and retrieving the specific settings you need each time you need them should be fine.  If you are concerned about your database performance, you could check them once at user log in and save them as session(if they are user-specific) or application variables.  However, the user would not see changes immediately, only after next log in.

Personally, I would go with the pure database option first and test it out.  If it doesn't perform well enough, it will be trivial to switch to the session/application variable option.

Comment: I don't understand why people always suggest storing *application settings* in the session. That means you're essentially copying the same data over and over again for each user. Pull directly from the database and if you want to reduce queries, *cache* the results in something like `MemoryCache`, `Redis`, etc. You should absolutely *not* use the session for this.

Comment: @ChrisPratt edited to put that

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well, essentially user session is the same as memory cache, just a dictionary.

Comment: Not at all. Session is per user, whereas memory cache would serve multiple users. By using the session you're storing the same global application settings again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your primary store as your database, but serve requests from the cache. Your DB is always going to be actual store, for cases where the cache recycles(could be in memory or even external/distributed cache)

Cache the frequently changed settings on app startup or on first access of admin actions.

Serve all subsequent operations to/from the cache. Any changes to the settings, update to and from the cache.

Run a job/service to sync the cache and the database, every hour or so.

### Pros:

- Access is fast, since it is coming from the cache.
- Updates are quick, since it is to the cache.
- Very less and predictable database access.

### Cons:

- The database is going to be behind by a max of an hour or so.
- In case of a cache recycle, you'll have an hour old stale data, but never a complete loss of it.

Answer (score 0):

i using this approach.. it using a json file. json file is very flexible for any type of value and it can be refresh when file change without application restart..

defining a config section..

```
namespace ConfigTest.Configuration
```

{
    public class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        private static JObject _props;
        private static FileSystemWatcher watcher;

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("path", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)this["path"]; }
        set { this["path"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("watch", IsRequired = false)]
    public bool Watch
    {
        get { return (bool)this["watch"]; }
        set { this["watch"] = value; }
    }



    private static JObject GetValues(string path)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(data);
        return j;
    }





    public static T Read<T>(string path)
    {
        var token = _props.SelectToken(path);
        if (token == null)
            return default(T);
        return token.ToObject<T>();
    }
    public static void Load()
    {
        MyConfig section = (MyConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myConfig");
        string path = section.Path;
        LoadValues(path);
        if (section.Watch)
            FileSystemWatcher(path);

    }

    private static void LoadValues(string path)
    {
        JObject props = GetValues(path);
        _props = props;
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher(string path)
    {
        if (watcher != null)
            watcher.Dispose();

        watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        watcher.Filter = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = (FileSystemWatcher)sender;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        LoadValues(e.FullPath);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


}
```

}

section definition

```
  <configSections>
  <!--important!! its should be your config type name space-->
  <section name="myConfig" type="ConfigTest.Configuration.MyConfig, ConfigTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```

configuration for setting file path and watch property

```
  <!--important!  locate it in App_Data or Outside the project directory-->
   <myConfig watch="true" path="yourpath/myConfig.json" />
```

config file myConfig.json

```
{
```

"someIntProperty": 1,
  "someStringProperty": "string",
  "someObjectProperty": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parentObjectName",
    "someChildeObject": {
      "childObjectId": 1,
      "childObjectName": "child object name "
    }
  }
}

how to use it..

u can get value with type

```
        int intvalue = MyConfig.Read<int>("someIntProperty");
```

u can get defined type object

```
    SomeClass objectValue = MyConfig.Read<SomeClass>("someObjectProperty");
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SomeClass2 SomeChildeObject { get; set; }


    }
    public class SomeClass2
    {
        public int ChildObjectId { get; set; }
        public string ChildObjectName { get; set; }

    }
```

or u can direct get any child with property path

```
string value = MyConfig.Read<string>("someObjectProperty.someChildeObject.childObjectName");
```

i hope this helpfull